# Изменение фокуса при слайде Android

Tags: android, xml, view

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть следующая верстка.
На этом экране надо пальцем поводить по области (покрытой серой сеточкой).
Если первое касание было в области этой области - все корректно, забираются координаты касания на этом вью и с ними происходят определенные действия

Вопрос в том как поймать фокус если пользователь нажал на экран в области слева или справа от этой области и продолжил "слайдить в этой области". Как переключить фокус на эту view?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, что если касание вне области, а потом в движении попадает в нее и это надо отследить? Если так то вам надо просто отслеживать попадание в эту область.То есть если вне области, то оставляем знак и при его наличии ищем область уже в движении.

```
enum StartTouch{
  IN_AREA,
  OUT_AREA
 }
private StartTouch start;

private Point area;



@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      int action = event.getAction();
      Point p = new Point(event.getX,event.getY);
      if(action== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(locArea(p)){
         start = IN_AREA;
         area = p;
      }else{
         start = OUT_AREA;
        }
      }if else(action== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(start.equals(OUT_AREA)&&locArea(p){
         start = IN_AREA;
         area = p;
       }
      return true;
}

private boolean locArea(Point p){
 // if(условие по которому определяем принадлежит ли точка области)return true;
 else return false;
{
```

Вот как то так. Писал код на сайте по этому возможны огрехи.

Comment: Проблема в том, что область View заканчивается в области где заканчивается сеточка.  Слева и справа от него родительский ViewGroup